# Geolocation check and error management for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, google-maps

I've written this code that I've been using for a while now to check for browser geolocation services for Google Maps applications. I have to say that I am not very happy with it as I've had to hack it quite a bit to work in IE9.

Could I please get some critical assessment of the following and possible suggestions for an elegant solution?  I need to stress that I do not want to use Modernizr or Gears. However, if there are good arguments, I'm willing to listen.

**Notes**: All the vars and functions in this script do pretty much as the function or var describes. All variables are declared as jQuery objects. `start()` launches Google Maps once the latitudes/longitudes are set.

```
function checkGeolocate()
{
    return 'geolocation' in navigator;
}

if (checkGeolocate()) 
{
    // Note that the if condition does not start until the end of the
    // entire geolocation procedure.

    if(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) 
    {
        userLat.val(position.coords.latitude);
        userLng.val(position.coords.longitude);
        userDist.val(25);

        start();

        mapControls.fadeIn(200);
        mapOverlay.fadeOut(100);
    }, 
    function(error) 
    {
        console.log(error);

        displayPostcodeSelect();
    },
    {
        timeout : 5000,
        maximumAge : 90000,
        enableHighAccuracy : true
    }))
    {
        // Do nothing as script has started
        // This if clause is to force IE9 to error out
        // instead of hanging when geolocation throws a PERMISSION_DENIED error.
    } 
    else {
        displayPostcodeSelect();
    }
} 
else 
{
    console.log('no geo support');

    displayPostcodeSelect();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tricky question,

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` will always return `undefined`, regardless of browser or whether or not the the user allowed the location to be retrieved.

That means that `//Do nothing as script has started, This if clause is to force IE9 to error out instead of hanging when geolocation throws a PERMISSION_DENIED error.` sounds like a superstitious approach. I believe you that it works, but it's not because you provided an empty `if`.

Also please read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.getCurrentPosition), if you must provide callbacks, then that means that `//Note that the if condition does not start until the end of the entire geolocation procedure.` is wrong.

From the little code in your question, I believe you should always call `displayPostcodeSelect` first, and if there is a geoLocation success you trigger your function. This means you no longer need to catch failures anymore since you want `displayPostcodeSelect` in that case anyway.

Furthermore, production code should not have `console.log`, it just looks bad.

Finally, 1 liner function that are used only once do not make sense, you should inline the `checkGeolocate` function.

All in all, I would counter propose:

```
//Start by showing the PostcodeSelect
displayPostcodeSelect();
if ('geolocation' in navigator) 
{
  var geoOptions =
  {
        timeout            : 5000,  //5 seconds
        maximumAge         : 90000, //1.5 minutes
        enableHighAccuracy : true
  };  
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) 
  {
        userLat.val(position.coords.latitude);
        userLng.val(position.coords.longitude);
        userDist.val(25);

        start();

        mapControls.fadeIn(200);
        mapOverlay.fadeOut(100);
  }, function(){}, geoOptions );
}
```

Comment: Apologies I haven't accepted this in such a long time.